# How to search on joining table in Rails 3 which doesn't have a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have two models `merchant` and `category` with a HABM relationship so have a joining table called `categories_merchants`

**How can I write the following query in ActiveRecords?**

```
SELECT
    categories_merchants.merchant_id
WHERE
    categories_merchants.category_id IN (1,2,3,4)
```

**NOTE:** The joining table doesn't have a model, it works automatically in Rails 3 without need for one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do such a query you should transform your HABTM in a `has_many :trough` and create a model for the joining table and query based on that.

Alternatively, **but possibly with worse performance**, you could do:

```
Merchant
  .select(:id)
  .joins("categories_merchants ON categories_merchants.merchant_id = merchant.id")
  .where("categories_merchants.category_id IN (?)", [1,2,3,4])
```

Comment: Since performance is not an issue, I tried using this type of query -- but keep getting a ```undefined method `where' for #<String:...>``` error